# Tkinter GUI welcmome window to load before python slot game

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been struggling for two weeks to try and get this code to load into a Tkinter GUI. I've come to the idea it would be easier to just load a welcome screen first and then the rest of the game in a normal window. However I can't seem to figure out how to get a Tkinter GUI window to load let along be the first thing to load before the rest of the game. I've imported tkinter and I also had an import for random when I was trying to get it to display solely in the tkinter window but I've now given up on that.

In previous work I've be able to get the follow tkinter codes to work in order to load a window but I haven't been able to get them to load in this,

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Window Title")
root.geometry("500x300")
root.configure(background='seagreen')
```

And this below in the current slot machine game code I'm working on. Alone it can work fine but as soon as I start adding the above code or anything similar it breaks. It will come up with an error at the beginning of root on the first line saying " unexpected indent " even if it is indented correctly

```
import tkinter
import random
print("Panther's Den Slot Machine. Please Answer with y/n")
print()
print()
print("Welcome to my den! You can win by rolling Ocelots, Jaguars, Boas, Caimans, Macaws or Tapirs. You can also with big with three Ibis.")
print()
print("You'll lose a coin for anything else, and if you roll three Scorpions say good bye to 500 coins")
print("Good luck kit!")
print()
print()

#create a window. set the title. set the size.
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Slot Machine")
root.geometry("700x400")

#a function that will pick (and display) a name.
#def pickName():
   # nameLabel.configure(text=random.choice(ITEMS))

#Displaying the name
nameLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text="PANTHER DEN", font=('Cambria', 60))
nameLabel.pack()

#Constants:
INIT_STAKE = 100
ITEMS = ["OCELOT", "MACAW", "JAGUAR", "IBIS", "CAIMAN", "BOA", "SCORPION", "TAPIR", "CONDOR", "BAMBOO", "FROG"]

first = None
second = None
third = None
stake = INIT_STAKE

def play():
    global stake, first, second, third
    playQuestion = askPlayer()
    while(stake != 0 and playQuestion == True):
        first = spin()
        second = spin()
        third = spin()
        score()
        playQuestion = askPlayer()


def askPlayer():
    global stake
    while(True):
        answer = input("You have " + str(stake) + " coins, Roll? ")
        print()
        if(answer == "y"):
            return True
        elif(answer == "n"):
            print("Game has ended. You won a total of " + str(stake) + " coins")
            return False
        else:
            print("Sorry, I didn't get that")

def spin():
      randomnumber = random.randint(0, 10)
      return ITEMS[randomnumber]

def score():
    global stake, first, second, third
    if((first == "OCELOT") and (second != "MACAW")):
        win = 5
    elif((first == "JAGUAR") and (second == "JAGUAR") and (third != "JAGUAR")):
        win = 8
    elif((first == "BOA") and (second == "BOA") and (third == "BOA")):
        win = 10
    elif((first == "CAIMAN") and (second == "CAIMAN") and ((third == "CAIMAN") or (third == "BOA"))):
        win = 8
    elif((first == "MACAW") and (second == "IBIS") and ((third == "MACAW"))):
        win = 15
    elif((first == "TAPIR") and (second == "TAPIR") and ((third == "TAPIR"))):
        win = 20
    elif((first == "IBIS") and (second == "IBIS") and (third == "IBIS")):
        win = 300
    elif((first == "SCORPION") and (second == "SCORPION") and (third == "SCORPION")):
        win = -500
    else:
        win = -1

    stake += win
    if(win > 0):
        print(first + '\t' + second + '\t' + third + ' -- You win ' + str(win) + " Coins")
    else:
        print(first + '\t' + second + '\t' + third + ' -- You lose')


#Background
root.configure(background='seagreen')

play()
```

Comment: "It will come up with an error at the beginning of root on the first line saying " "unexpected indent " even if it is indented correctly." I'm sorry but no it won't. You must have an indentation problem. A likely problem is mixing tabs or spaces or your text editor changing things when you copy paste (try retyping everything, no copy/pasting). This is not a tkinter problem

Comment: can you post a **minimal** non-working version with the entire stack trace?

Comment: I can see that your program does not contain a `mainloop()` also if you were to put a mainloop at the end it would never be reached due to the play() leading to a while loop.

Comment: @Mike-SMT People that use IDLE to write code don't need a `mainloop()` call, since IDLE runs in the REPL.

Comment: @Novel that may be but they are still stuck in the `play()` loop and it needs to be re-written to work within a GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code to work within a Tkinter application. That said it is not perfect and will need some work on the layout but should be a good start to getting you on the right track.

I believe the major problem you were having was being stuck in the `play()` loop and thus the code never made it to the `mainloop()` for tkinter. This prevent a GUI from being brought up.

I modified the `play()` function to work with a button in Tkinter instead. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

intro = """Panther's Den Slot Machine.


Welcome to my den!

You can win by rolling Ocelots, Jaguars, Boas, Caimans, Macaws or Tapirs.
You can also with big with three Ibis.

You'll lose a coin for anything else, and if you roll three Scorpions say good bye to 500 coins

Good luck kit!"""



root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("700x400")
root.title("Slot Machine")
root.configure(background='seagreen')

INIT_STAKE = 100
ITEMS = ["OCELOT", "MACAW", "JAGUAR", "IBIS", "CAIMAN", "BOA", "SCORPION", "TAPIR", "CONDOR", "BAMBOO", "FROG"]

first = None
second = None
third = None
stake = INIT_STAKE

nameLabel = tk.Label(root, text="PANTHER DEN", font=('Cambria', 60))
nameLabel.pack()
lbl = tk.Label(root, text=intro, background='seagreen', font=('Cambria', 12))
lbl.pack()
lbl2 = tk.Label(root, text=stake)
lbl2.pack()

def play():
    global first, second, third
    first = spin()
    second = spin()
    third = spin()
    score()

def quit_play():
    lbl.config(text="Game has ended. You won a total of " + str(stake) + " coins")

def spin():
    randomnumber = random.randint(0, 10)
    return ITEMS[randomnumber]

def score():
    global stake, first, second, third
    if((first == "OCELOT") and (second != "MACAW")):
        win = 5
    elif((first == "JAGUAR") and (second == "JAGUAR") and (third != "JAGUAR")):
        win = 8
    elif((first == "BOA") and (second == "BOA") and (third == "BOA")):
        win = 10
    elif((first == "CAIMAN") and (second == "CAIMAN") and ((third == "CAIMAN") or (third == "BOA"))):
        win = 8
    elif((first == "MACAW") and (second == "IBIS") and ((third == "MACAW"))):
        win = 15
    elif((first == "TAPIR") and (second == "TAPIR") and ((third == "TAPIR"))):
        win = 20
    elif((first == "IBIS") and (second == "IBIS") and (third == "IBIS")):
        win = 300
    elif((first == "SCORPION") and (second == "SCORPION") and (third == "SCORPION")):
        win = -500
    else:
        win = -1

    stake += win

    if(win > 0):
        lbl.config(text="{}\t{}\t{} -- You win {} Coins".format(first, second, third, win))
        lbl2.config(text=stake)
    else:
        lbl.config(text="{}\t{}\t{} -- You lose".format(first, second, third))
        lbl2.config(text=stake)

tk.Button(root, text="Play", command=play).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly! I've adapted it so I've got quit and exit buttons for the game. Thank you!

Comment: @12williamsa glad to help.

Comment: I come up with an ideas to allow the user to enter a name to play with for the game. I've partly had text-entering boxes working but nothing solid. Would you know of a way to get one working?

Comment: @12williamsa should be simple enough. Using a entry filed for the user to type a name then use the `get()` method on the entry filed and assign the string to a variable. It would be best if you post a quest with what you have tried so far and explain where you are stuck so someone can assist.

Comment: Here we go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51757544/adding-tinkter-entry-box-to-run-in-game-gui-or-its-own-gui-before-game